# Keyboard layout in LUKS prompt

Tags: lubuntu, keyboard-layout, luks

I have been using Lubuntu with LUKS encrypted disks with at least 4 previous Lubuntu releases. The keyboard layout in LUKS passphare prompt has been the same as in the whole system.

Yesterday I installed Lubuntu 17.10 with LUKS encrypted disk (using alternate installer because creating LUKS encrypted disk did not work from live session (didn't work with 17.04 either)). The installation went well but when I restarted the computer, the keyboard layout in LUKS prompt was US.

Obviously something has changed in installation process. But how can I change the keyboard layout in LUKS passphrase prompt?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer after some searching... it's a bug in `initramfs-tools`
bug reported [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/initramfs-tools/+bug/1719612)

The solution found there as a temporary work around is:

```
sudo ln -s /etc/console-setup/cached_UTF-8_del.kmap.gz /etc/console-setup/cached.kmap.gz
sudo update-initramfs -u
```