# Change GRUB Keyboard Layout from English to German

Tags: grub2, keyboard-layout

I am facing a problem with grub. After a fresh install of Ubuntu 17.10 Grub is using the English keyboard layout instead of a German one. This applies to the Grub console and to the LUKS password prompt that opens directly after the boot manager. Since I am using full disk encryption with a rather strong passphrase, I have to adapt it to the US keyboard layout.

I have tried [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/751259/how-to-change-grub-command-line-grub-shell-keyboard-layout) solution but it did not work. The layout remains English without any errors or messages. Moreover, I can't use the keyboard in the bootmanager at all. So I reverted the changes suggested in the solution.

I never faced this problem before.

Comment: As I have stated in my question, the proposed solution in this question does not solve the problem. Moreover, it deactivates the keyboard during the GRUB screen. When prompted for my password the keyboard layout is still English.

Comment: Since the accepted solution in the proposed duplicate didn't solve your issue please [edit] your post to include your `grub-kbscomp` command and it's output as well as the content of `/etc/grub.d/40_custom
` Thank you for helping us help you!

Comment: Infact I solved the problem. It is a bug in ´initramfs-tools´ in Ubuntu 17.10 and derivates (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/console-setup/+bug/1719612).  (cf. https://askubuntu.com/questions/977489/keyboard-layout-in-luks-prompt)