# LUKS Encrypted Hard Drive — Passphrase includes '£'

Tags: encryption, keyboard-layout, luks

I recently changed my passphrase through 'Disks' and I've included the character £ in it. I realise now that the UK keyboard mapping only applies after this is done, so trying to type £ gives me # instead (I'm assuming, I can't see the password).

How do I type £ at the screen 'cryptsetup: please unlock disk'? None of the AltGr+Number or Shift+Ctrl+Something I've looked up seems to work, apart from sometimes shutting off the screen. (e.g. when I press down one of the arrow keys. Why is that?)

Hopefully this won't need any personal technical details but if it does I'll put it here.

Comment: Is it too early for [code points](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/tips-specialchars.html#ctrlshiftu)?

Comment: maybe this helps: https://askubuntu.com/questions/977489/keyboard-layout-in-luks-prompt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Setup keyboard/locale in initramfs

1. Edit `/etc/initramfs-tools/initramfs.conf`

   - `KEYMAP=y`
2. Update initramfs

   - `sudo update-initramfs -u`

Ref: [How to set keyboard layout in initramfs](https://wiki.debian.org/Keyboard#How_to_set_keyboard_layout_in_initramfs)

#### Workaround

> This might be a good idea if your disk is removable.

1. Use an Ubuntu image and boot from that using CD/DVD or thumb drive.
2. Setup your locale and keyboard.
3. Identify encrypted file system.

   - This will be something like `/dev/sda2`
4. Add password without £

   - `sudo cryptsetup luksAddKey /dev/sda2`

Comment: I don't know how to edit from this screen. Plus, secure boot is enabled (Does this change anything?)

Comment: Followed the workaround. I was hoping for a better solution but thanks anyway.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, but you should be able to update initramfs by using a similar workflow to the Workaround, but you'd need to mount the decrypted filesystem, `chroot`, and perform the instructions.  Now that you have access, you can do the first set of instructions to prevent this in the future.